# C# selenium if statement

Tags: c#, selenium

So I'm using an if statement and I would assume if that statement doesn't find/do what it's suppose to, then it should throw an exception right? Well for some reason I'm getting absolutely nothing, the if statement isn't working, yet I'm not getting an exception?

Example of code -

```
try
{
    label1.Text = "Finding route";

    string sxp = "//*[@id='s']";

    if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("sxp")).Count != 0)
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(sxp)).Click();
        label1.Text = "sxp done";
    }
}
catch
{
    CheckRoute();
    label1.Text = "Exception thrown";
}
```

and the response from my program is nothing as soon as it hits the " if " statement, because before that it changes label1 to specified string..

Comment: Put `else throw new Exception();` after if statement.

Comment: Where are you throwing an exception? I can't see any in that code.

Comment: Exceptions are used to indicate that an error has occurred while running the program. Exception objects that describe an error are created and then thrown with the throw keyword. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions

Comment: @Polyfun I thought if " try " failed it would throw the " catch " ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are checking it with `if` statement it has nothing to do with `Exception throw`. Remove `if` and it will throw an `exception` when it cant find the element. Also access the message with `e.Message()` if I am not mistaking. In your case it should be `ElementNotFoundException`.

```
 try
 {
     label1.Text = "Finding route";
     string sxp = "//*[@id='s']";
     driver.FindElement(By.XPath(sxp)).Click();
     label1.Text = "sxp done";
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     CheckRoute();
     label1.Text = "Exception thrown";
 }
 catch(ElementNotFoundException e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about `if`s and how they work. `if`s don't throw exceptions if they don't evaluate to `true`. Exceptions are thrown in specific cases when something unexpected happens. On example would be if you used `driver.FindElement()` and the element wasn't found... that would throw an ElementNotFoundException.

In your case, you have done the right thing and used `.FindElements()` (plural) and because of this, your code will not throw an exception. So, because of this you can remove the `try-catch` and additional simplifications result in the code below.

```
label1.Text = "Finding route";
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> routes = driver.FindElements(By.Id("s"));

if (routes.Count > 0)
{
    routes.ElementAt(0).Click();
    label1.Text = "sxp done";
}
else
{
    CheckRoute();
    label1.Text = "sxp not found";
}
```

I stored the resulting collection from the `.FindElements()` in a variable, `routes`, so that it can be reused. Your code was hitting the page twice. I removed the `try-catch` because it was not needed.